# Improving the stored procedure performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which runs very slowly. I am trying to understand if it is about my query or it is some kind of index issue. Here is the key part which I am thinking the reason of the slowness;

```
where ([Code] in (select * from dbo.Split(',',@code)))
```

There are 1170 comma delimited value which is returned from `dbo.Split` function and the `[Code]` column comes from a table which consist of over 6 million rows. I have index for `[Code]` column in my table. The query runs about 10 minutes.

Is that normal to have such a slow result or can it be improved? Thanks.

Comment: I am certain this can be improved. But you have to share your code. AND the split function which is very likely a major portion of the issue.

Comment: split `@code` into a table, create an index and check if you have a better performance doing a `JOIN`.

Comment: You have tried to run only `Select * from dbo.Split(',',@code)` ? 
How much time it takes? 
You have to make Inner Join, not where condition.

Comment: @ValiMaties, yes and it works just in 0 seconds.

Comment: How about main select, without where clause. How much time it takes?
Every where clause MUST have index(es). 
Run an Estimated Execution Plan over the query and check if you have missing indexes... If so, I propose, as @JuanCarlosOropeza did, to make a table with your split function and create indexes as you can optimize it with the main table from which you retrieve data...

Comment: @ValiMaties, I am giving it a try right now. When it results, I am going to share it here.

Comment: @ValiMaties, the main select  with inner joins and without where clause takes about 3 minutes and returns 44.000 rows.

Comment: It's clearly you miss indexes.. for 44000 lines, 3 minutes is a very long time. Your table is not indexed or your indexes are a lot fragmented.

As I said, run an Estimated Execution Plan over your query and check which index is missing. Create it and you will see how quickly the result will be shown.

Comment: I'd move your where clause to the from by using ---> join dbo.Split(',',@code) split on split.val=[Code]

Comment: The use of `in` with a subquery is probably preventing the optimizer from using an index on `code` (if one is available).  You may want to dump the results into a temporary table with the code column as the primary key.

Comment: That is what I said. Just try the temporary table.

Comment: My two cents: in order for `[Code]` index to be used column types and sizes must match. If `dbo.Split` returns `VARCHAR( MAX )` then indexes only will not help, you need to use a temp table with column type exactly matching `[Code]` column type.

Comment: I have used a temp table with [Code] being the primary key and it improved my performance very well.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a Common Table Expression:

```
with cteCode 
as
(
   Select ColumnName --Avoid using *
   From dbo.Split(',',@code)
)
Select Col1, ColN
From MainTable mn
Where exists ( select top 1 1 
               from cteCode cc
               Where cc.ColumnName = mn.Code )
```

**Aditional tips:**

- Check for Indexes fragmentation, perhaps you need to give them some
  maintenance
- Avoid using functions into the where clause

Good Luck

Comment: Should be able to just INNER JOIN cteCode without EXISTS.

Comment: The same plan will be generated in this scenario

Comment: May be true, but readability would be improved, for future query modification :)

Comment: This will actually guarantee that index will not be used, whereas advice above (insert result of Split into table variable and join with main table) actually might. Actual plan will depend on cardinality of Split and existence of covering index on [Code].